# convert content of text file to json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new bee to python I need your help/suggestion, I am trying to convert the content of text file to json using python

filename is json_content.txt. Below is the content of text file

```
hostname : WGNAIOP
fsystem : /dev/sdb
actual_size : 2.5T
used_disk : 609G
avail_disk : 1.7T
percentage : 26%
mount_disk : /data

hostname : WNQAIOP
fsystem : /dev/sdb
actual_size : 2.5T
used_disk : 526G
avail_disk : 1.8T
percentage : 23%
mount_disk : /data
```

I have tried in multiple ways but i am unable to get the result in json format.
Please help me to know how i can convert the above text data into json

Thanking in Advance!!!

Comment: Data is in single line or in multiple lines .i.e, separated by new line after each parameter?

Comment: How should your JSON file look like?

Comment: @prudhvi: data is in multiple lines i.e 7 lines. I had added line by line but it took in a single line

Comment: @anna, look for below format
 {
    "hostname" : "WGNAIOP",
    "fsystem" : "/dev/sdb",
    "actual_size" : 2.5T,
    "used_disk" : "609G",
    "avail_disk" : "1.7T",
    "percentage" :  26%
    "mount_disk" : "/data"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_data = {}
with open("json_content.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line != "\n":
            split_data = line.split(':',)
            print(split_data)
            json_data[split_data[0]] = split_data[1].split('\n')[0]

print(json_data)
```

Output:

```
{'hostname': 'WGNAIOP', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'used_disk': '609G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T', 'percentage': '26%', 'mount_disk': '/data'}
```

Comment: thanks for the support
i am getting below error as
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest2.py", line 6, in <module>
    json_data[split_data[0]] = split_data[1].split('\n')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Is this the same text in text file, check whether you have empty lines in your file ?

Comment: @Shrikant Check the updated code. If you had empty lines in your text file.

Comment: yes there was a empty line in my file after removing it, it worked, Many thanks for the support

Comment: Present code will work if you have empty lines also.

Comment: need your support here
I am adding more content to my file as below, having set of 7 lines and a blank line then continued with set of 7 lines

hostname : WGNAIOP
fsystem : /dev/sdb
actual_size : 2.5T
used_disk : 479G
avail_disk : 1.9T
percentage : 21%
mount_disk : /data

hostname : WGNZJOQ
fsystem : /dev/sdb
actual_size : 2.5T
used_disk : 526G
avail_disk : 1.8T
percentage : 23%
mount_disk : /data

when i try to print into json it is going into infinite loop.
I am looking to print first 7 line into json and after a blank space print next 7 lines into json

Comment: Just add else statement and print the json in else and clear the json content

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have any whitespaces in either the key or the value, you can use this regular expression to transorm your content to a dictonary:

```
line = 'hostname : WGNAIOP fsystem : /dev/sdb actual_size : 2.5T used_disk : 609G avail_disk : 1.7T'
d_items = re.findall(r"(\S+\s:\s\S+)", line)

d = dict()
for d_item in d_items:
    k, v = d_item.split(" : ")
    d[k] = v
```

For the lines provided the snippet works:

```
print(d)
# {'hostname': 'WGNAIOP', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'used_disk': '609G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T'}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to experiment with `^\s*([^:]+)\s*:([^:]+)\s*$`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar solution as the other answer.

```
import re
import json

tfile='/home/json_content.txt' 
input = None
with open(tfile) as infile:
    input = infile.readline()

# remove leading and trailing double quotes if needed
# input = input.strip('"')
pattern = re.compile("\S* : \S*")
match = pattern.findall(input)

data = {}
for kvp in match:
    values = kvp.split(' : ')
    data[values[0]] = values[1]

data_json = json.dumps(data)
print(data_json)
```

Comment: i dont want to explicitly define the string as input = "", instead i want to read the content of a file from a particular path
i tried with below as but it is not working
tfile='/home/json_content.txt'

with open(tfile) as infile:

Comment: Think you're on track there. Just need to read data from file after opening it. See if updated answer works for you.